# R How to use next row for same column calculation

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, lag, lead

I've been trying to replicate some basic Excel calculations in R but I can't find the right solution for this one.

I want to create a new column of a `data.frame` but the values being calculated should be based on the next values of the same column, so it is kind of being calculated from down-up.

I am able to do it using values of the same column (previous ones) but doesn't work for the next ones.

First part of my approach works fine (when using next values of another column), but not in the same column.

In excel it is simple but can't make it work.

Also, I don't know if a for loop is the best option, I have to do it with 1 million rows `data.frame` so it may be slow.

Thank you in advance.

```
p <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,6,8,9,10)
g <- c(4,4,3,4,5,6,6,6,8,0,0)
data <- data.frame(p,g)
a <- 2
```

My approach

```
data$f2<- 0
for (i in 1:nrow(data)){
  data$f2[i] = data$g[i]*a+data$g[i+1]*a+data$g[i+2]*a+data$f2[i+1]*a+data$f2[i+2]*a
}


#Output
   g f2

1  4 22
2  4 22
3  3 24
4  4 30
5  5 34
6  6 36
7  6 40
8  6 28
9  8 16
10 0 NA
11 0 NA
> 

#Desired Correct Output

    g    f2
   
1     4 11232
2     4 11232
3     3 11232
4     4  4106
5     5  1498
6     6   540
7     6   192
8     6    60
9     8    16
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on your logic a bit more?

Comment: @markus for example in excel, C2 value depends on C3 value and C4 value, the more rows you add (or drag in excel) upper rows are recalculated. This C2 (in my approach f2) should be the new column created. Hope it is more clear now. Thanks again

Comment: You have not still said how you get the required results. eg how do you get 16? row 9 then how do you get 60? then how do you get 192?

Comment: Sorry for my explanation, every f2 row is obtained by same row column g* a, row+1 column g*a, row+2 column g*a, row+1 column f2*a, row+2 column f2*a. Row nine is 8*2, the rest of values are 0. Row 8 is 6*2+8*2+16*2, Row 7 is 6*2+6*2+8*2+60*2+16*2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`base R` solution

**Code:**

```
data$f2 <- 0

for ( i in rev(seq_len(nrow(data)-2))) {
  data$f2[i] <-  with(data, sum( na.omit( c( g[c(i + 0:2)], f2[c(i + 1:2)])) * a                               
                               ) 
                     )
}
```

**Output**

```
 data
 #    p g    f2
 #1:  1 4 83882
 #2:  2 4 30698
 #3:  3 3 11232
 #4:  4 4  4106
 #5:  5 5  1498
 #6:  6 6   540
 #7:  7 6   192
 #8:  6 6    60
 #9:  8 8    16
 #10:  9 0     0
 #11: 10 0     0
```

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67375268/1691723) may show wrong value.  Row 3 should be 11232 and not 11234. Please verify and confirm.

Comment: works great! Thank you so much, you are rigth row 3 is 11232 as you said. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

This looks like an `Arma` calculation.
You could use the `filter` function from `signal` package :

[image]

```
library(signal)

a <- 2
f <- signal::Arma(b=rep(a,3),a=c(1,-rep(a,3)))

signal::filter(f,sort(g,decreasing=T))
# [1]     16     60    192    540   1498   4106  11234  30704  83898 229218 626238

data$f2 <- sort(signal::filter(f,sort(g,decreasing=T)),decreasing=T)

# A tibble: 11 x 3
       p     g     f2
   <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
 1     1     4 626238
 2     2     4 229218
 3     3     3  83898
 4     4     4  30704
 5     5     5  11234
 6     6     6   4106
 7     7     6   1498
 8     6     6    540
 9     8     8    192
10     9     0     60
11    10     0     16
```

Some remarks :

- Not sure why your calculation doesn't go beyond 11234
- The coefficients of this `Arma` filter diverge as shown by `zplane` below : the `x` (poles of the filter) should all be within unit circle for a stable filter.
  This is not the case => results will be `Inf` before reaching the million rows

```
zplane(f)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'll go for another option as I probably need different coefficients and more rows, thank you again!